# Use nextAuth to authenticate an external api (nestJS)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js, nestjs, next-auth

I'm setting up a local monorepo with a nextjs frontend and nestjs backend, using nextauth to authenticate via google.

I am able to login and get the session using just the nextjs app/api routes, and I can validate the session on the nextJS backend using `getServerSession`, so I believe my config is correct.

However when I send a request from a page, directly to the nestjs backend, I am unable to validate the session within an auth guard. Is this possible?

NextJS is served locally on port 3000, Nest is served on 8080

#### web/pages/api/auth/[...nextauth.ts]

```
export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env["GOOGLE_ID"] ?? "",
      clientSecret: process.env["GOOGLE_SECRET"] ?? "",
    }),
  ],
}

export default NextAuth(authOptions)
```

#### api/src/auth-guard.ts

```
import { CanActivate, ExecutionContext, Injectable } from "@nestjs/common";
import { getServerSession } from "next-auth";
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google";
@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  async canActivate(context: ExecutionContext): Promise<boolean> {
    const req = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();
    const res = context.switchToHttp().getResponse();

    const session = await getServerSession(req, res, {
      providers: [
        GoogleProvider({
          clientId: process.env["GOOGLE_ID"] ?? "",
          clientSecret: process.env["GOOGLE_SECRET"] ?? "",
        }),
      ],
    });

    return !!session;
  }
}
```

#### web/pages/profile/index.tsx

```
import { signOut } from "next-auth/react";
import { Button } from "@chakra-ui/react";
import { useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

export default function ProfilePage() {
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchthings = async () => {
      await axios.get("http://localhost:8080/gym", {
        withCredentials: true
      });
    };

    fetchthings();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      profile
      <Button
        onClick={() =>
          signOut({
            callbackUrl: "/",
          })
        }
      >
        Log out
      </Button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

#### api/main.ts (nest)

```
import { Logger } from "@nestjs/common";
import { NestFactory } from "@nestjs/core";
import { AppModule } from "./app.module";

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);

  app.enableShutdownHooks();


  app.enableCors({
    origin: "http://localhost:3000",
    credentials: true,
  });

  await app.listen(8080);

  Logger.log(` Application is running on: ${await app.getUrl()}`);
}

bootstrap().catch((ex) => {
  console.error(ex);
});
```

Comment: Different ports === no session cookie. Look at the request headers in the dev tools.